# Performing viewshed analysis in R?

Tags: raster, r, viewshed

I have made some web search but coultn't find any answer regarding how to perform viewshed analysis in R without the use of external tools (e.g., GRASS). I do know that a number of interesting packages are available in R to perform viartually all types of GIS-related operations, from visualization to spatial analysis with all which lies in-between, but I seem to not have found anything regarding viewshed.

I need to have a package which does not require the use of external tools, such as GRASS or ArcGIS for instance.

Comment: Did you find `rpygeo.Viewshed.sa` at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPyGeo/RPyGeo.pdf ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will surely dig down into that package, which did not show up in my web searches. Still, I do not understand why my question has been downvoted.

Comment: That package is the second question (under this one) that shows up in a search for "viewshed" under the R tag: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+viewshed

Comment: I have edited my original question to stress that I was referring to R packages that do not need any other external tool to run a viewshed. Also, I am going to post an answer to elaborate on a possible viable approach to address my question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have found a viable solution to address my (edited) original question. At the best of my web searches, I got the impression that virtually all the packages available in R to perform viewshed analysis are actually resting upon external tools, such as GRASS or ArcGIS. The same holds true for the packages pointed out to me in some of the comments I got. What I actually need is to perform viewshed from scratch in R, and I was in search of a piece of code (however provisional). I have found a nice answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841387/r-code-that-evaluates-line-of-sight-los-between-two-lat-lon-points

A sample code is also provided, which give at least some bases for possible further improvements.